# PHP: best method to trim a substring from a string

Tags: php, string

Want to process a set of strings, and trim some ending "myEnding" *from the end* of each string *if it exists*.

What is the simplest way to do it?
I know that everything is possible with regexp, but thus seems to be a simple task, and I wonder whether a simpler tool for this exists.

Thanks

Gidi

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->replaceSuffix('myEnding')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/ea3e40132e9d4ce27da337dae6286f2478b15f56/src/Str.php#L442) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ima go with preg_replace on this one.

```
$output = preg_replace('/myEnding$/s', '', $input);
```

Comment: Tanks for the valuable answer, even though I asked for non regexp solutions

Comment: you asked for the simplest way to do it. in this case, regex was the simplest way.

Comment: Regexp is a hero :)

Comment: If your string to remove (e.g., myEnding) is from user input or otherwise can't be trusted, be sure to use [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). So, something like this: `$output = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($myEnding) . '$/s', '', $input);`

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is the slower solution, regexp is not really efficient for simple tasks like this.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$s = "foobarmyEnding";
$toRemove = "myEnding";

$len = strlen($toRemove);
if (strcmp(substr($s, -$len, $len), $toRemove) === 0)
{
    $s = substr($s, 0, -$len);
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/mYNYl)

Comment: This is probably much faster than regex for such a simple task.

Answer (score -5):

`rtrim` http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

```
$str = "foobarmyEnding";
$str = rtrim($str, 'myEnding');
// str == "foobar"
```

ltrim is the same deal for the start of a string http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

You could also use str_replace to replace a search term with with an empty string but its slower then rtrim/ltrim if you need to amend the start or end of a string

Comment: Not really. The second parameter to `rtrim` is a list of characters to strip. It's not handled as an entire string.

Comment: The question was "trim some ending "myEnding" from the END of each string"

Comment: If your string contains any of those characters directly before "myEnding", they will get stripped as well. Let me give an example: what happens when you input "HelloMikeShermanmyEnding". You'd expect the output to be "HelloMikeSherman" but the output will be "HelloMikeSherma"! Because "n" is part of the character list provided to `rtrim`.