# How do I get a part of a string in php?

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a function that returns a string `"_" . $mime_type . ".jpg"` by default.
If the output string returns for example `"_jpg.jpg"` I want to remove the `"_"` and the last part `".jpg"`. Thus, returning the string `"jpg"`. What php function should I use?

Comment: This is too localized. Edit your question to specify a general pattern that you need, rather than only including the exact text.

Comment: Which ones have you tried? *related*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637398/php-best-method-to-trim-a-substring-from-a-string

Comment: It sounds silly that the function returns the concatenation of strings that I want to remove. But long story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$old_string = "_jpg.jpg";
preg_match('/_(.*)\./', $old_string, $matches);
if (!empty($matches)) $new_string = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match) is the way to go